# Integrating into Windows Explorer context menu

Tags: c#, .net, explorer, file-extension

I want to write a small tool, that does the following:

When you right click on a file with a certain file-extension the Windows Explorer context menu shows an additional entry.

When you click this entry a certain EXE is launched with this file as one of its parameters.

I would like to use C#/.NET 2.0 for this. If it's not possible I could also do it with C++/Win32.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible with C# .NET 2.0?
2. What are the necessary functions for integrating into the Windows Explorer context menu?
3. How can I make this permanent? (I don't want to relaunch this tool after every boot)
4. What do I have to take special care of? (different OS, security permissions, etc.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You will need to access the registry and add a key under `root\\File\\shell` or `root\Folder\\shell`, depending on which items you want the menu item visible on.

Try [this article at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/appendmenu.aspx), it's quite useful.

Edit: There's [another article here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/SimpleContextMenu.aspx) which may be of help.

Comment: +1 for the link to the great 'simple shell context menu' project.

Answer (score 5):

It is, incidentally, not supported to use .NET for shell extensions, due to the current inability to host multiple runtime versions in the same process (.NET 4 will lift this restriction).

Consider the case where you have two shell extensions; one for .NET 3.5, one for .NET 1. Which runtime will get loaded into your process?  Well, it's more or less random--it depends which shell extension gets loaded first. Sometimes it might be the 2.0 runtime, sometimes it might be the 1.1 runtime.

This is also an issue if a .NET program creates common file dialogs; your shell extension may or may not load, and may or may not run with the correct runtime version.

As such, if you go down the [Shell extension route](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776881(VS.85).aspx) you should use native C++/COM/Win32.

Comment: The latest .Net 4.0 runtime supports in process side-by-side loading of the .Net 4.0 runtime (and ALL future runtimes) with earlier .Net runtimes.

See following excerpt from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx 
"With the ability to have multiple runtimes in process with any other runtime, we can now offer general support for writing managed shell extensions—even those that run in-process with arbitrary applications on the machine."

Comment: The [SharpShell](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus) project makes shell extensions easier using newer runtimes.