# Windows Explorer Menu using C#

Tags: c#, winapi, contextmenu

I need to add items to explorer context menu. When files/folder are selected different menu items should be visible in context menu.

1. Sub-menus
2. Menu icons
3. Support to interact with different file types
4. Support multi selected files and folders

I have read about [IContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776881(VS.85).aspx#IContextMenu).
There is no native support in .NET framework, but I appreciate sample code that uses WIN32 API or implements [IContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776881(VS.85).aspx#IContextMenu) written in C# (No matter framework version).

MS.Net 4.0 [side-by-side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx)

The following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838856/integrating-into-windows-explorer-context-menu) is not what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this working robustly in managed code you will have to use .NET 4.0.

The [**All-In-One Code Framework**](https://web.archive.org/web/20180123005238/http://1code.codeplex.com:80/) contains an [example for managed shell extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/codefx/)
(CSShellExtContextMenuHandler).