# How to add a menu item in Windows right-click menu

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I want to develop a simple window tool, to add a menu item in window right-click menu.

For example, I open "computer", navigate to C:, and right click on the free space, and I will see a menu.

Here,I want to add some items, just like bookmarks to store some disk locations I always visit

How to add the item... Can you give me some advices ? thanks

by the way, I use C# language to do this tool

Comment: You mean something like this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838856/integrating-into-windows-explorer-context-menu

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to write a [shell extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows Explorer. This extension will execute in the Explorer.exe process and previously it was not recommended to implement the extension using .NET because only one version of the .NET runtime could be loaded into Explorer.exe process. However, in .NET 4 it is possible to load multiple version of the .NET runtime within the same process making it possible to write shell extensions using .NET. For more information you can read the article [How to Write Windows Shell Extension with .NET Languages](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/174369/How-to-Write-Windows-Shell-Extension-with-NET-Lang) on Code Project.

Answer (score 9):

I hope [add any application to the desktop right click menu in vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/)

OR [add any application shortcut to windows explorers context menu](http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/)

will resolve your issue.

Comment: My problem in particular will be more easily solved by this. Sometimes, the programmer in me thinks first of writing the code. Sometimes, the solutions are as simple as yours :-)