# Menu in python with encrypt & decrypt

Tags: notepad

PLEASE HELP

How to make a menu that can encrypt and decrypt a message from notepad. Please respond as soon as possible.
I have tried on a number of different sites and I'm getting very frustrated with this problem.

Comment: Menu in what? Do you mean a context menu in Windows Explorer?

Comment: If so, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838856/integrating-into-windows-explorer-context-menu