# Interaction of other programs outside application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cross-application

This is a bit hard to explain...
Essentially what i want is something like 7zip. You can either use 7zip file manager and right click items to zip it there, OR you can right click on any item outside 7zip, say a folder in desktop, and have the option of using 7zip. How do i achieve this using a C# application? Can you guys point me in the right direction?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838856/integrating-into-windows-explorer-context-menu

Answer (score 0):

You must create a DLL and register it as a Shell Component of Windows. 
[See here](http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/) the manual steps to perform it. You just have to create an installer to perform same things.