# Add right-click context menu only in desktop

Tags: c#, .net, windows-explorer

I know how to implement a context menu over a file or folder

[Integrating into Windows Explorer context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838856/integrating-into-windows-explorer-context-menu)

[How add context menu item to Windows Explorer for folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders)

but I want to know how to put a command in the context menu in the desktop right-click without right-clicking on a file or folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144110.aspx

I think the registry path for the desktop background is HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/DesktopBackground, but looking through my registry I can see some of the handlers I see on my dekstop under /Directory/Background as well.